# Best way to sync podcasts into Windows Mobile phone?

Tags: windows-mobile, podcasts

I have yet to find an application that best synchronizes podcasts with my phone, at least one that is as good as iTunes.

I wanted an application that:

- downloaded the new podcast episodes,
- synchronize them with the phone, and, most importantly,
- *delete the episodes already played on the phone*.

Is there an application like this?

Right now I use iTunes to download the episodes, Windows Media Player to do the sync and I have to manually delete the played episodes...

Answer (score 1):

- [Getting Podcasts onto your Smartphone](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikehall/archive/2005/03/07/389162.aspx)
- [HOW-TO: Get podcasts and videos on Windows Mobile Smartphones](http://www.engadget.com/2004/12/16/how-to-get-podcasts-and-videos-on-windows-mobile-smartphones/)

Comment: that's pretty much the same solution I have, except that instead of iTunes i use Doppler or iPodder. Does any of these detect the already played episodes and automatically delete them?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. Seems odd to automatically-delete a podcast because it was already played though. Typically, they will mark the podcast as "played," similar to how email clients mark email read.

Comment: Well most of my podcasts have 5-minute episodes which are delivered daily. When using iTunes, whenever I click the "Update" button the episodes marked as played are deleted while the new episodes are retrieved. However, I still have to manually mark episodes as played.

Comment: Articles say it could work with iPodder but it couldn't, only Doppler create playlist for WMP and WMP can synchronise only by playlists (or individual files but this is not useful)

Answer (score 0):

[BeyondPod](http://www.beyondpod.mobi/)

Best pod catching/playing software I have found.